# Is it legal having two 40 hour jobs in 2 EU countries being non EU

Tags: contract-law, employment, european-union, tax-law, immigration

I have a work permit in Sweden for 3+ years.

I have received a job offer from another EU country.

I want to work both jobs. Both jobs are 55k+ euro annually so I have no issues with minimum requirement etc.

Both jobs are remote but the new company wants me to register in either Spain or Portugal and get work permit/authorization.

Is it legal to:

Go to Spain/Portugal and get a work permit there and register. Come back to Sweden and continue doing both jobs.

Comment: Sounds like you're setting yourself up for various problems. (1) You might lose both the Swedish and Spanish permits. (2) The 2nd company is probably not ultimately interested in you having a work permit, but wants you to actually work from those countries. After all, employment laws, social security, and so on generally depend on the country you actually work from, and the company doesn't want to deal with Swedish rules. (3) Working 2× 40 hour jobs would mean you get insufficient rest. This would be a legal problem for both employers. If you work less than that, this might be time theft fraud

Comment: @amon How will the Swedish government know I am also working somewhere else? Is there information sharing between the 2 governments in terms of work permits issued? 
How will the Swedish tax agency know that I am also paying taxes in Spain/Portugal?

Comment: @Are you asking whether it’s legal, or whether you’ll get caught?

Comment: @Sneftel Will i get caught?

Comment: @Sneftel And what is illegal about it?

Comment: I am paying taxes in both countries. Legal in both countries. Not committing any crime.

Comment: @Arthie that’s not what I asked. If you’re concerned with legality rather than whether you’ll get caught, why ask how they’d find out?

Comment: @Sneftel
I am concerned about both

Comment: A critical piece of info you're leaving out is how your Swedish employer feels about you getting another "full-time" job and whether or not the Spanish/Portuguese company is aware that you plan on keeping your current job when you start working for them.

Comment: @brhans The companies are not competitors and that should be fine. Do you know about the legalities?

Comment: "How will the Swedish tax agency know that I am also paying taxes in Spain/Portugal?" Because you have to list your foreign income on your Swedish tax filings. If you don't do that, we can add tax fraud as yet another issue. "The companies are not competitors and that should be fine." It's not fine because they are competing for your time. Under EU rules, employers have to ensure you get sufficient rest. Your 1st employer won't want you to work additional jobs if that impacts your work performance.

Comment: You can go to https://www.reddit.com/r/overemployed/ to get the answers you want to hear. The people over there celebrate juggling multiple jobs. But they're not necessarily interested in handling legal challenges, like correctly taxing income from multiple countries or maintaining desired immigration status.

Answer (score 4):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany) **No.**

There are limits on the number of hours you can work, on the number of vacation days you *must* take, and so on. These limits require that your primary employer is made aware of any other jobs, and that those other jobs fit into the maximum hours.

Two times 40 hours is way over the limit.

Comment: The 48-hour-per-7-days-period limit is part of EU legislation, BTW, so it definitely applies to the OP's question as well.